# returning a function that is already inherited

Tags: go

an interface has been added to the structure.

```
type contextableStream struct {
    grpc.ClientStream
    recvTimeout, sendTimeout time.Duration
}

func NewContextableStream(stream grpc.ClientStream, recvTimeout, sendTimeout time.Duration) *contextableStream {
    return &contextableStream{
        ClientStream: stream,
        recvTimeout:  recvTimeout,
        sendTimeout:  sendTimeout,
    }
}
```

The methods `ClientStream` can be used.

```
func (s *contextableStream) CloseSend() error {
    return s.ClientStream.CloseSend()
}
```

Why did a person write such a function? The person did not try to satisfy any interface

Answer (score 0):

In short: embedding an interface type into a struct implicitly satisfies the interface

---

[grpc.ClientStream](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientStream) - as you have identified - is an interface type.

This interface type is [embedded](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#embedding) in the struct type `contextableStream`. This essentially makes `ClientStream` an anonymous field of the struct `contextableStream`. Also by being an anonymous field, it makes the struct implicitly satisfy the interface - without any extra struct method definitions.

`NewContextableStream` initializes a `contextableStream` - assigning the embedded anonymous field with a value:

```
func NewContextableStream(stream grpc.ClientStream, ....) *contextableStream {
    return &contextableStream{
        ClientStream: stream, // the parameter stream is now stored in the struct
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

this anonymous embedded field value is of type `grpc.ClientStream`. To reference it, one uses the type name:

```
s := NewContextableStream(stream, 0, 0) // stream is stored in s

var i grpc.ClientStream
i = s.ClientStream      // interface value of type grpc.ClientStream
```

and this interface has all the methods defined in that interface, so one can invoke:

```
i.CloseSend()
i.SendMsg(...)
i.RecvMsg(...)
```

In any of the above calls, one is essentially invoking a methods on the original parameter value `stream` passed to `NewContextableStream` i.e.

```
stream.CloseSend()
```